# Making non-autonomous systems into autonomous: confusion with partial derivatives

Tags: derivatives, dynamical-systems, partial-derivative

Consider
[image]

For example consider
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix} \dot{x}  \\ 
\dot{y}  \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} tx \\ 
 y +  t \end{pmatrix} .
\end{align*}
If I were to let
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{z} = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ 
 y \\ 
  t \end{pmatrix} 
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}
\dot{\mathbf{z} }  = \begin{pmatrix} t x \\ 
y + t \\ 
1 \end{pmatrix} 
\end{align*}
Then we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \dot{ \mathbf{z}} }{\partial  t} = \begin{pmatrix}  x \\ 
 1 \\ 
  0 \end{pmatrix} .
\end{align*}

But this doesn't seem enitrely right. I think that now that $t$ is coordinate we should have
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \dot{ \mathbf{z}} }{\partial  t} =\mathbf{0} . 
\end{align*}

Question: What is going with the the derivatives and which is which?

Comment: You could make this autonomous but then it will be nonlinear. That would make it harder to solve.

Comment: How did you arrive at $\frac{\partial z}{\partial t} = (x, 1, 0)^{\mathrm{T}}$?

Comment: Define the autonomous system as $z=(x, y, \theta)$, with $\dot{z}=(\theta x, y+\theta, 1)$. Your confusion arises because the solution to $\dot{\theta}=1$ is $\theta=t$ (plus an arbitrary constant), but $\theta$ and $t$ are different entities.

Comment: Thank you @Gonçalo for the comment. Just to make sure I am following the logic here, we define the new system as you have mentioned above. Solve it and then look at the particular case when $\theta = t$. This should give the solution to the original system. Correct?

Comment: Correct. ${}{}$

Comment: Great. Feel free to post this as an answer and i will accept it to mark the question as answered.